When are orientations on the faces of a tetrahedron induced from the boundary map?
My original problem, stated at the end of the post, seems to have been too abstract to attract comments/answers. I'll try prepending it with a more concrete question:
Consider a tetrahedron with corners labelled $0,1,2,3$. The four triangular faces of this tetrahedron, (1,2,3), (0,2,3), (0,1,3), (0,1,2) can be assigned orientations by selectively (for each face) transposing two labels or not. For instance, a possible alternative assignment of orientations is:
$(1,2,3), (0,3,2), (0,1,3), (1,0,2)$
This particular assignment has the special property that it is induced by the boundary operators $\partial_i$ (defined near the end of the post).
The following assignment of orientations:
$(2,1,3), (1,0,3), (0,2,3), (2,0,1)$
is not induced by the boundary operator, but if the original tetrahedron labelling is permuted by a single transposition $(2 1)$, then it again induces this assignment with the boundary operators.
Finally, note that the assignment:
$(1,2,3), (0,2,3), (0,1,3), (0,1,2)$
does not arise from the boundary maps, regardless of how the tetrahedral labelling is permuted.
Question: which assignment of face orientations are induced by the boundary operators, after a possible permutation of the corner labels?
Below is the original text of my post. I'm not sure that the current one is much more enlightening, but we'll see....

The $n+1$ maximal faces of an $n$-simplex can be assigned orientations in $2^{n+1}$ ways. Any labelling of the vertices of the $n$-simplex by $0<1<2<...<n$ induces a particular element of these $2^{n-1}$ via the boundary maps:
$\partial_i : (0,1,2,\ldots, n) \mapsto (-1)^i[0,1,2,\ldots,\hat{i},\ldots,n]$
For example, the orientations $[1,2]$, $[2,0]$, $[0,1]$  of the 1-faces of a 2-simplex can be induced this way. On the other hand, the orientations $[1,2]$, $[0,2]$, $[0,1]$ cannot arise this way, regardless of the vertex labelling.
How can one determine if a given assignment of orientations of the maximal faces of an $n$-simplex can be induced from the boundary maps, for an appropriate vertex labelling?  Moreover, if such a labelling exists, how can one be found?
